# Error-handling with usage of `$@`

Tags: perl, error-handling, eval

My aim is to check several input files (`file1`,`file2`) for keywords (`key1`,`key2`,`key3`) and match a number. If an error occurs, the program shouldn't stop and check the next word/file. I want to give an adequate error output.
My code so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach ("key1","key2","key3"){output("$_","file1")}
foreach ("key1","key2","key3"){output("$_","file2")}
foreach ("key1","key2","key3"){output("$_","file1")}

sub parse{

my $keyword = shift;
my $path = shift;
my $match;

eval{
        open(FILE,"$path") or die "Cannot open file $path in parse(): $!\n";
        while (my $line = <FILE>) {
                if ($line =~ /^$keyword\s+(\d+)/){ ;
                        $match = $1;
                }
        }
        return (1, $match) if (defined $match);
        return (0)
    };
if ($@){print "!!! Error in parse():\n\t $@\n";}    
}

sub output{

my $keyword = shift;
my $path = shift;
my ($ok, $tmp);

($ok, $tmp) = parse("$keyword", "$path");
print "Value $tmp for keyword: $keyword\n" if $ok;
print "!!! Error for keyword: $keyword\n" if not $ok;

}

1;
```

with file1:

```
key1    11
key2    22
key3    33
```

and file2:

```
key1    11
key2    AB
key3    33
```

Without the `eval`-block the program runs like expected: If e.g. `file2` is missing, an error occurs and Perl quits. With the `eval`-block the correct matching occurs and I only get the **!!! Error for keyword** for errors on specific lines of my input files (if the input file misses at all, I get errors for each line). But I can't use the `$@`. This creates errors for each line.

I also tried to use `close` or `open` without `die`, but this isn't working neither.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're reopening the file for each keyword. Pass all the keywords into `output`/`parse` so you only open each file once.

Comment: Thx but why is the file reopened when I am not returning the keywords to `output` / `parse` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're returning values in `eval` block.

Just like subroutines, the return value of `eval` is the value of the last line inside, or the value you returned before the last line using `return`. So, if you return value in `eval` block, you were passing it to the `parse` subroutine, but you didn't return it to `out` subroutine. And that's why `$ok` is always `undef`.

Consider this piece of code：

```
my $ret = eval{
        open(FILE,"$path") or die "Cannot open file $path in parse(): $!\n";
        #open(FILE,"$path");
        while (my $line = <FILE>) {
                if ($line =~ /^$keyword\s+(\d+)/){ ;
                        $match = $1;
                }
        }
        return (1) if (defined $match);
        return (0);
        #close(FILE);

};
print "$ret\n";
```

You will see 1 if the file matches. But still you should return the value passed from `eval` blocked to `out` subroutine.

Comment: I'd put the `eval` around the call to `parse`, return `$match` and check if it is defined in `output`

Comment: @RobEarl Agreed. Although this program would be functionally correct after fixing the bug mentioned, it has some aspects to improve within the structure design.

Comment: Thx @Xu Ding. So the `return` in `eval` is kinda useless? Because I don't have to return `$match` (if it is defined) and still can use it after the `eval`-block. 

I adopted your code snippet and added `if ($@){print "Error in parse():\n\t $@";}; return ($ret, $match);` before the end of the `parse`-subfunction. This works.

Comment: @bashophil Good for you :)

Comment: I accept your answer because it solves my issue, but I would be really interested in additional information regarding the `return`.